# angular reactive form toggle validation required?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have this radio button asking (do you have massage certificate?) if yes it will show the file input. I want this file input not required be default and if the user select yes it will become required. I have this code below that set cert validation to null by default and if has has_cert become true then set cert validator but its not working.. I need your help guys. Thanks in advance.

```
<p>Form value: {{ form.value | json }}</p>
<p>cert input : {{ form.get('cert').status | json }}</p>
```

.ts

```
form: FormGroup;
has_cert = new FormControl(false || true);
has_exp = new FormControl(false || true);
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.form = new FormGroup({
        ...
        has_cert: new FormControl(''),
        cert: new FormControl(''),
        ...
    })

    this.form.get("cert").setValidators(null);

    this.form.get('has_cert').valueChanges.pipe(
        filter(value => value === false || null)
    ).subscribe(
        () => this.form.get('cert').setValue(''),
        () => this.form.get("cert").setValidators(null)
    );

    this.form.get("has_cert").valueChanges.pipe(
        filter(value => value === true)
    ).subscribe(
        () => this.form.get("cert").setValidators(
            [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern('^.*\.(doc|DOC|docx|DOCX|pdf|PDF)$')
            ]
        )
    );
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's not working for you? Cross field validation or enable/disable of `cert`?

Comment: I yes, I want to enable validation when user select yes and disable validation when user select no

Comment: Got it! Can you can create a stackblitz fork?

Comment: You can use Cross Field validation https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar Hi, I have updated the code in my question

Comment: You can refer to **MustMatch** validator from https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-validation?file=app%2F_helpers%2Fmust-match.validator.ts

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `form.get('something').setValidators(...)` for each cases.

Comment: Hi @Liu Zhang, I have tried that but Ican't remove the validator if has_cert become false
this.form.get('has_cert').valueChanges.pipe(
      filter(value => value === false))
    .subscribe(() => this.form.get('cert').setValue(''),
      () => this.form.get('cert').setValidators([])
    );

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code in my question

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Liu Zhang's answer, I believe you can use clearValidators to remove all the validators you added with setValidators.